# Spring Session: Change the name of 'x-auth-token'

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-session

Does anyone know how to override the header name 'X-Auth-Token'?

We are using it mostly for session management (not auth) and want to give it a different name. Can't find anything online about this.

Comment: Define a `HeaderHttpSessionIdResolver` as a bean in your configuration and pass the name of the header you want to use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your configuration add a `HeaderHttpSessionIdResolver` type bean.

```java
@Bean
public HeaderHttpSessionIdResolver httpSessionIdResolver() {
  return new HeaderHttpSessionIdResolver("Your-Header-Name-Here");
}
```

and it should automatically pick that up and use it.